# Spring boot uber jar can't read @Value from .properties file

Tags: spring, maven, jar, spring-boot

My Spring Boot application works fine when lunched from Eclipse IDE, but when I execute an uber jar I get the exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${device.port}"
            at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

which indicates that value of this:

```
@Value("${device.port}")
private String port;
```

is not the value set in the .properties file located in src/main/resources:

```
device.port=5672
```

but just a string "${device.port}" which is later on parsed to Integer.

@PropertySource("classpath:default.properties") is set correctly, this is how my main function looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}
```

This is my part of pom.xml which might be crucial for solving my problem:

```
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>com.devices.App</mainClass>
                </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>make-assembly</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

How to make my uber jar read the data from .properties file? I believe I must be missing something silly. Probably I have to indicate somewhere in configuration that I want my .properties file to be included in uber jar.

Comment: Why are you even using the assembly plugin and not the spring-boot plugin which takes care of all that for you?

Comment: @m-deinum I'm unaware. Thank you for pointing that out. I will take a look into that.

Comment: @m-deinum: You are right. maven assembly plugin is messing things up. "spring-boot-maven-plugin" takes care of everything. Thank you for your tip.